# Android arrayadapter on spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I want to populate a spinner with some values from a List
The list is populated with objects

```
    ArrayAdapter<PersonDetails> toStopAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<PersonDetails>(MoreTicketSalesActivity.this, R.layout.generic_spinneritem,
                                R.id.spinner_item_name, personDetails);
    Spinner.setAdapter(toStopAdapter);
```

My PersonDetails class looks like this

```
    private int id;
private int index;
private String name;
```

At the moment when i set the adapter the personDetails is full with data
But on my spinner is displayed some strange text "com.project.person ..."

What i do wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a simple display for each element of the spinner.  What does 'generic_spinneritem' look like?

The simple answer is to make sure your PersonDetails class overrides toString and returns the name (or whatever you want).  Right now its showing a class name.

For more complicated row display, you'll need to create a custom adapter and override getView.